# Login to Realm Server on Android

Tags: android, realm

I'm pretty new to Android and just jump straight to it. My question about Realm is that I try to login into the Realm Object Server and it always throw out the UNKNOWN error, following the Realm Task in demo app and it's working fine but moving back to my own app, it stuck at the login step. I set a debug at AuthenticateResponse result in SyncUser and after that it immediately failed to login. Below is my code.

```
public void login(String username, String password) {
        SyncCredentials myCredentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username, password, false);
        SyncUser.loginAsync(myCredentials, realmIP, this);

}
```

I also implemented the onSuccess and onError function.
My app on iOS and Mac works perfectly fine without any trouble but this is my first time in Android and I don't know where I made a mistake. I have searched around but seems like there are no answers. 
Sorry If I asked a stupid question or already answered question.

Comment: Did you add Internet permission to the android manifest?

Comment: I already did it, yeah, I compared to the RealmTask demo app but honestly I did not find anythings, from the manifest to the grade build, I tried to do exactly the same. Usually it should have some meaningful errors but this time it was UNKNOWN error and I don't know where I should go to fix it.

Comment: UNKNOWN indicate an unexpected exception. The `ObjectServerError` class should contain the exception message if you call `error.getException()`

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I'm in the same scenario. Working fine on iOS but not android